# Setting GOPATH on Ubuntu - still getting error

Tags: ubuntu, go, environment-variables

I have set following path on my `~/.bashrc` file

```
export GOPATH=/usr/lib/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

But when i installed ATOM IDE and i tried to install `go-plus` package, it tired to download something at the end and i got the error that

```
package github.com/nsf/gocode: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

What I am doing wrong ? Here is my ubunt information as well.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

**P.S**

I have already tried setting my

```
export GOPATH=/home/<username/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay guys, I figured out the problem.

https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/issues/386

here it has been discussed. I will just copy it from that

Linux folks, particularly those running Ubuntu. I believe I have reproduced your issues and I think they have to do with where you are setting your `GOPATH` and `PATH`.

- `~/.profile`: If you set them here, `$GOPATH` will be set in Atom when you launch Atom for the first time from the launcher in the toolbar
- `~/.bashrc` If you set them here, `$GOPATH` will be set in Atom when you launch Atom for the first time from the terminal
  Thus, to ensure `GOPATH` and `PATH` are set correctly regardless of how you launch Atom, you should put the following (or similar) in both `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`:

> ```
> export GOPATH=$HOME/work
>
> export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
> ```

Obviously the above doesn't apply exactly if bash isn't your default shell, but I trust that if you're a user of a different shell, you can grok what I am saying above and apply the same principles to your particular environment.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on OSX. Weird in my case was that `process.env` showed I am using normal bash. This was strange, because I am using zsh. The environment variables overall were wrong and did not match the environment in my terminal at all.

[image]

Turned out I needed to set zsh as default shell. This added zsh to the list of known shells and made it the default for my user. Note that `xh3b4sd` is my username.

```
command -v zsh | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
chsh -s $(which zsh) xh3b4sd
```

After restarting my mac the environment in the output of `process.env` was correct and `go-plus` worked as expected.

[image]